# Keycload Admin Api - logout-all endpoint not working

Tags: api, keycloak

When calling the /{realm}/logout-all endpoint, the request always results in a "500 - Internal Server Error" and "error": "unknown_error" in the body. All other endpoints work as they should.

I made sure to call the endpoint with a new token and the Authorization-key in the header of the request. All calls are made from postman for testing.

Did I miss something?

Edit 1:

Keycloak Version: 12.0.2

The call: (generated the token with the admin-cli client and the admin user, so pribvileges shoudln't be a problem (?))
[image: The call]

The log:
[image: The log]

Comment: What does it show in the Keycloak logs?

Comment: Wow, i feel pretty dumb at moment, the thought didn't occur to me. `16:40:52,290 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-5) Uncaught server error: org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: org.keycloak.representations.adapters.action.GlobalRequestResult of media type: application/octet-stream` I have yet to google it, but on the first glance I have no idea what that means :(

Comment: Nothing to feel dump about it; it happens xD

Comment: For reproducibility, which keycloak version are you using? would also be nice to have a print or something about how you are actually making the call to the logout endpoint

Comment: @dreamcrash Thanks for your comment. I added the version and screenshots from the call and the log to the question.

Comment: I was also able the reproduce

Comment: @dreamcrash Okay, I had that problem now for a long time, but was able to solve it last week :) You have to set the "Accept: application/json" header on the request. I guess the application/octet-stream is a fallback, which doesn't even exists.

Comment: Ahaha very good :) almost one year afterwards, good catch nonetheless. You can provide an answer, maybe it can help someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference and anyone who has the same problem with Keycloak:

In some of the requests (e.g. logout-all) you have to provide a `Accept: application/json` header, otherwise Keycloak defaults back to application/octet-stream, for which Keycloak is missing the necessary classes.